# how to require HTTPS but not redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.net Core application with an API section.  I want to Require Https for all access to the API.

However [Asp.net docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) states

> **Warning**
>
> Do not use RequireHttpsAttribute on Web APIs that receive sensitive
>   information. RequireHttpsAttribute uses HTTP status codes to redirect
>   browsers from HTTP to HTTPS. API clients may not understand or obey
>   redirects from HTTP to HTTPS. Such clients may send information over
>   HTTP. Web APIs should either:
>
> - Not listen on HTTP.
> - Close the connection with status code 400 (BadRequest) and not serve the request.

**Question**

Is there a way to reject but not redirect incoming https on a controller/method level?

Comment: originally asked 2 related questions I chose to move the second question to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229638/how-can-you-tell-if-a-request-came-in-via-http-vs-https-in-visual-studio  for clearity.

Comment: Do you want this on specific controllers/actions, or in the entire application?

Comment: for now, I'm looking for just a controller or action.  currently, other controllers for the same project should have the redirect behavior?  But really either will do I can always split the API section into a new project.

Comment: `Is there a way to reject but not redirect incoming https `? if (!Request.IsSecureConnection) return BadRequest(); But you can't really prevent the client from sending it.

Comment: If so, then writing an `Attribute` or using a BaseController on the controllers you want which then overrides `OnActionExecuting` method to check the Request `Scheme` and proceed by either returning a `BadRequestResult`(400) or  `Forbidden` (403) result

Comment: @Steve Right i can't prevent any client from sending bad info. but I can fail. hopefully, that will give them enough of a clue to resend via https.

Comment: If the data is sensitive at all, the application should not listen on HTTP at all

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I would agree if it was a pure API site, but the redirect from Http to https seems correct for a user using a browser to access the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using asp.net core, let's write an `ActionFilterAttribute` that we are going to apply to any controllers or actions that we want return a *Forbidden* result instead of a *Redirect* if the request scheme is **HTTP** and not **HTTPS**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RestrictHttpsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.IsHttps)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
}
```

**How To Use**

This is how to use the action filter on a controller:

```
[RestrictHttps]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    // controller code goes here.
}
```

For further reading, checkout [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: thank you. I was going bad and forth between forbidden and bad request.  to me, Forbidden is you have accessed the right place but you are not allowed in.  Bad Request is this not a valid way to access the selected resource.  I plan to use with the flop to bad request. thank you good write up.

Comment: Good idea, glad I could help. Cheers!