# How can you tell if a request came in via HTTP vs. HTTPS? in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017, I'm building an ASP.NET Core site.

How can you tell, in the controller, if a web request came in via HTTP vs. HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Request.IsHttps`

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var isSecure = Request.IsHttps;

    // Do Something

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple THanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`Request.IsSecureConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2) will tell you if the request came over SSL.

If you are using .Net Core, the property name is [`Request.IsHttps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.ishttps?view=aspnetcore-2.1).